# How to setup CloudCode from parse in mac

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am taking refernce form [this](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?onboard=#hosting/unix) link.

I have installed parse from command given.

Now whenever i run this command:

```
parse new MyCloudCode
```

Instead of asking my email and password i am getting this messages:

```
 unexpected arguments:[MyCloudCode]

Creates a new Parse app and adds Cloud Code to an existing Parse app.

Usage: 
  parse new [flags]

Global Flags:
  -h, --help=false: help for new
```

How can  I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

> parse new

You will be prompted to give the directory name in later steps.